# jQueryUI menu hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-menu

I create a menu using UL element, I am using jQueryUI to show this menu.

```
<ul style="display:none" id="action_menu" class="menu">
    <li><a href="javascript:alert(213112);">Edit Translation</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Edit Comment</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Edit Bind</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Edit Reuse</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Edit Sync Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Export</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Show History</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Upload Screenshot</a></li>
</ul>
```

When a button is clicked, $("#action_menu").menu() can show this menu. 
and I know how to show this menu, and now I have no idea how to hide this menu when mouse click on other place not click on the menu. I find so many examples, they add document click listener, and check whether the event target's parent node is this menu. Like this link [Hide dropdown menu jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349879/document-click-to-hide-menu) does anyone have better idea, i wondering why jQueryUI doesn't add an event or option for menu widget. Someone help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a general solution i don't know about your plugin

```
$(document).click(function (e)
{
    var container = $(".menu");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have read this kind solution somewhere, it looks Jquery UI doesn't take document click menu hide into consideration, i have to solve this problem like this. Thank U, Arun Killu

Comment: I've got same problem. When I implemente this solution, the click on the button which open the menu don't do anything more. Any solution ?